# Reload View on change url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using [`angularjs`](https://angularjs.org/) with [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (with the helper [`stateHelperProvider`](https://github.com/marklagendijk/ui-router.stateHelper)) to collect views and controllers into the page.

But got a problem with my views not updating.

## My code (the one that is related)

config.js

```
app.config(function($httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider, RestangularProvider, stateHelperProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    stateHelperProvider
        .state({
            name: 'division',
            url: '/division/:division',
            views: {
                'main': {
                    templateUrl: '/templates/division.main?uri=' + segment(2),
                    controller: 'DivisionController'
                }
            },
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'appcontent',
                    url: '/content',
                    views: {
                        'content': {
                            templateUrl: "templates/division.appcontent?uri=" + segment(2) + '&root=' + segment(4),
                            controller: 'AppContentController'
                        }
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'root',
                            url: '/:root',
                            views: {
                                'roots': {
                                    templateUrl: "templates/division.appcontent.roots?uri=" + segment(2) + '&root=' + segment(4)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
});
```

the code I use for linking

```
// linking to another division
<a ui-sref="division.appcontent({division: 'test2')">test2</a>

// linking to another root
<a ui-sref="division.appcontent.root({division: 'test2', root: 'test')">test2</a>
```

## Explaining

But got a problem with my views not updating.

My views are the one with the actual data, so I need them to reload on change.

Like when `:division` in url is `test1`, then the template `template/division.main` have one set of data. But when `:division` in url is `test2`, then the template `template/division.main` have another set of data.

So whenever `:division` in url changes, I need to reload the template `template/division.main` and as well all the child templates.

But when `:root` changes in the url, I only need to reload the template `template/division.appcontent.roots` and not the `template/division.main` template.

Is this possible somehow or should I change to use only an API in order to get data.

I really hope this makes sense.

#### Note

`segment` is a function I have made to get some data from the angular route.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662818/angularjs-ui-router-reloadtrue-also-reloads-parent-state

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem. This uses Javascript in order to change the content inside the view. My view is based on PHP which makes it impossible to get the right data without reloading the view or creating an API to get data through. Thanks anyways.

Comment: According to http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider, templateUrl can be a function which is passed the current state params...  `templateUrl: function(params) { return myTemplates[params.pageId]; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863125/reload-view-on-change-url?noredirect=1#comment44142507_27863125) from [@ChrisT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225368/chris-t) I managed to get it to work using templateUrl as a fucnction.

My new config.js:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider, RestangularProvider, stateHelperProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    stateHelperProvider
        .state({
            name: 'division',
            url: '/division/:division',
            views: {
                'main': {
                    templateUrl: function(params) {
                            return '/templates/division.main?uri=' + params.division;
                    },
                    controller: 'DivisionController'
                }
            },
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'appcontent',
                    url: '/content',
                    views: {
                        'content': {
                            templateUrl: function(params) {
                                return 'templates/division.appcontent?uri=' + params.division + '&root=';
                            },
                            controller: 'AppContentController'
                        }
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'root',
                            url: '/:root',
                            views: {
                                'roots': {
                                    templateUrl: function(params) {
                                        return 'templates/division.appcontent.roots?uri=" + params.division + '&root=' + params.root;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
});
```