# unable to call $stateProvider, twice to update the view (it is only working for the first time)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a search books page, in which when I click the search tab, depending on the search criteria, it will display the results in the adjacent block. But when I click it second time, it is not working!

The relevant html code of the page:

```
<form action="#" method="post" ng-controller = "OptionsController as oCtrl">

         <select class="selectpicker btn btn-default" name="SearchCriteria" id ="sOptions">
                <option value="1">Title</option>
                <option value="2">Author</option>
         </select>

         <label class="searchbox">
         <span><br></span>
               <textarea id="searchBox" name="searchBox" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="search books"></textarea>
         </label>

         <input type="button" value="Search" id = "bsearch" class="submit button" ui-sref = ".searchResults">                       

        </form>
<div id = "spaceforresults" ui-view = "" autoscroll="false"> </div>
```

My angular js code for routing

```
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
.state('books.searchResults', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'html/searchResults.html',
    controller: 'BookController',
});
```

So, when I click the search button, the results are popped out as expected. Then If I change the options and click the search button again, it is not routing the view (updating the results). Am I doing anything wrong over here?

Comment: Your form should not have an action or method ....

Comment: Removing the action and method didn't resolve the issue. Anyway, I got it and posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer! By using $state.go in a different state, we can explicitly ask the router to reload the content based on the event triggered.

Then my angularjs code is modified to

```
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
.state('books.searchResults', {
url: '',
templateUrl: 'html/searchResults.html',
controller: 'BookController',
})

$stateProvider
.state('books.reloader', {
controller: function($state) {
      $state.go('^.searchResults');
    }
});
```

and in the form,

```
<input type="button" value="Search" id = "bsearch" class="submit button" ui-sref = ".reloader">
```

This answer was taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662818/angularjs-ui-router-reloadtrue-also-reloads-parent-state/27665507#27665507)

Answer (score 1):

## Reload

Just set your state reload to be true example below

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); //second parameter is for $stateParams
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/angular-js-angular-ui-router-reloading-current-state-refresh-data/23609343#23609343) please give original author props.

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can use this on a button click. So try it with that first and then move it to everywhere you change state to get every page to refresh.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that $stateProvider.go is not a function

Comment: You're just using `$state.go` though right? and you've injected it into the controller right?

Comment: I'm loosing the scope of $stateProvider in the controller (I defined it as $stateProvider instead of $state in the beginning)

Comment: That reloads the complete state

Comment: $state.reload() does reload the resolves, but doesn't reinitialize the controller with the newly resolved values. Since the whole point of reloading the resolves is to refresh the scope with the new data, reinitializing the controller is a requirement for $state.reload() to be of any use.